# How to modify crontab to run python script?

Tags: python, linux, cron, redhat

I am using redhat linux platform
I was wondering why when I use python script inside crontab to run every 2 minutes it won't work even though when I do monitor the crond logs using
tail /etc/sys/cron it shows that it called the script , tried to add the path of python , [ I am using python2.6 -- so the path would be /usr/bin/python2.6 ]

the crontab -e [tried user and root same problem ]

*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python2.6 FULLPATH/myscript.py

Comment: What does `myscript.py` does it have any relative imports? That may cause the script to fail.

Comment: indeed it does import to connect to oracle database import cx_Oracle but that is not the case here it doesn't even execute I tried to make the script print something on a file whenever it gets called , nothing happended , @AnandSKumar

Comment: Does the script start with #/usr/bin/python2.6? Does the script have execute permission set?

Comment: yes it has , and I tried to add the #!/usr/bin/python2.6 at the beginning @mpez0 , I am testing simple script on a another machine , just a script to append a line on a file no database related imports or function , it seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys , but I did a little research and I have found a solution , first you have to test sudo python to see if it works with the module , if not you have to do alias for the sudo you put it inside /etc/bashrc [ to make it system wide alias ] , alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME TNS_ADMIN=$TNS_ADMIN'
Then you have to change crontab to call a script to assign these values to the variables , using source /the script && /usr/bin/python script.py